# regEx for Florida Drivers License

Tags: jquery, regex

I have a mask using a jQuery plugin `$(#example).mask(A999-999-99-999-9);` to match a Florida Drivers License Number. What I am trying to figure out correctly is how to write a regEx for 
A999-999-99-999-9. This is what I have come up with so far does anyone have any advice or pointers?

```
("^[A-Za-z]{1}\d{12}$")
```

or

```
("^[A-Za-z]{1}\d{3}[- /]\d{3}[- /]\d{2}[- /]\d{3}[- /]\d{1}$")
```

Comment: what's wrong with the second one, i think you just need to escape the backslash one more time.

Comment: You haven't explained what the valid format or content of a Florida drivers license number is, and I've never lived in Florida to be familiar with it. What defines a valid number? What are some sample numbers that should match, and what are some that should fail? And what particular regex dialect are you using?

Comment: The repeat count of `{1}` is superfluous but not harmful at the end of the second regex.  You don't enforce the same separator throughout a single licence number.  You do demand a separator with the second one.  But it should work OK.  What is the problem?  Does the sub-species of regex that you're working with not recognize the Perl-ish `\d` notation?  Does your host language require that the backslashes are doubled up (two backslashes in the source code to get one backslash in the regex string)?

Comment: I suggest you don't be too strict about what you accept. One day they'll change it, if they haven't already.

Comment: It would if you explain what you mean by *mask*. You've not tagged with any language or mentioned one in the question content, and haven't mentioned (again) what regex dialect you're using, so your use of *mask* wasn't clear. You need to remember when posting here that we *only have the information you provide in your question itself* - we can't see your screen or read your mind to determine what you mean.

Comment: It was, but you need to [edit] your question and put that information there where people can see it as part of your question. I see someone else has already edited to provide the missing jQuery tag. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be all you need:

```
"^[a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{12}$"
```

I would take the mask out though incase you want to add other states. Unless you have the mask change to match the regEx of each state.

Answer (score 1):

Are you going to accept dashes as optional? If not, it's pretty straightforward:

```
/\A[A-Z]\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{3}-\d\z/i
```

If you are going to accept dashes as optional, then what are valid replacements? In your example you have both optional dashes and `[- /]` expected; are those all the valid separator characters, and if so, do you want them to be optional? If so:

```
/\A[A-Z]\d{3}[ /-]?\d{3}[ /-]?\d{2}[ /-]?\d{3}[ /-]?\d\z/i
```

But really, it would be easiest to just first process the input to remove anything that isn't alphanumeric, then test the result:

```
input.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/i, "").match(/\A[a-z]\d{12}\z/i)
```

Comment: Hi @chris Heald Is there any pre-defined repository to find regular expression to capture driving license number of every state in USA? Like here https://ntsi.com/drivers-license-format/

Answer (score 0):

Well…this may be not a "professional" answer but I think it would work:

```
/[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{3}\W[0-9]{3}\W[0-9]{2}\W[0-9]{3}\W[0-9]{1}/
```